# Adaptive Payments VS Website Payments Pro for our online marketplace

Tags: paypal

We are a UK-based marketplace site that wants to never force buyers to sign up for paypal. We allow users to set up customized stores through our site, and our second requirement is that these users be able to become sellers with only a basic paypal account. When a buyer makes a purchase, we are the primary receiver, taking 15% and passing on the entire paypal fees to the secondary receiver (user), as well as all the remainder of the transaction. My question is: What's the best solution paypal offers for this? It seems that chained payments would be, but if I understand correctly the Website Payments Pro system is the only one that guarantees that buyers outside the UK wouldn't need a paypal account. Is there a way to take the money in ourselves with Website Payments Pro and use the API so it transfers the 85% (minus the fees) to the user's paypal account?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what approach you want to take.

I would prefer Chained Payments as it allows guest checkout (credit card payments outside a PayPal account) with certain restrictions and will easily allow the user to receive the funds and automatically forwards the 15% cut to your account. This removes the need to collect funds outside of the payment flow. This means no invoicing or no lost dues!

Website Payments Pro only offers credit card payments however you would also need to offer Express Checkout for PayPal payments as well. You also have the flexibility of hosting the order form so you control what the users see. The downside is you'd have to collect funds from the user outside the payments. Such as monthly invoicing, billing agreements or manual processing.

Here is the criteria we use to allow guest checkout. Please keep in mind these are due to rules and regulations, not PayPal's choosing.

- The credit card has a lifetime limit of 10 purchases outside a PayPal account
- The user's email address must not be attached to an existing PayPal account

I don't have a direct answer for you but hopefully this helps make your decision.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The only reason chained payments doesn't seem like the answer for us is because I was told that as a UK company, anybody residing outside the UK would have to have a paypal account to purchase from the site (I was told guest checkout was disabled for goods that cross international borders). 

As for Website Payments Pro, we would be collecting 100% of the money (minus fees), and then transfering 85% minus the fees to the user's paypal account. Can you confirm that's free? Would the API have a feature that allows automatic invoicing and transferring of that money?

Comment: Chained Payments does allow guest checkout for cross boarder transactions. There are some countries we don't do business with or have certain restrictions and these buyers may not be able to pay using a credit card. This is a buyer limitation rather than a limitation of your own.

If you decide to go with Website Payments Pro you can use the following to disburse payments. Simple Payments allows you to choose how the fee is applied. Mass payments require you to pay the fee before sending the funds to the customer.

 - Adaptive Implicit Simple Payments
 - Mass Payments